# Grouped and Stacked Column Charts

Tags: powerbi

[the image shows the stacked column chart visual in power bi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNkMQ.png)
my requirement is I need the visual grouped according to the legend which is region in this case and the axis sorted by y axis

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't group a stacked chart with the native visual. You can with custom visuals like Deneb though.